# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to class name

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to work with Arrays and methods for the first time and I can't understand how can I "feed" my object with my array values.

The error is:

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to > ArrayMethod

`ArrayMethod` is the name of my class.

```
public class ArrayMethod {
    static int[] values = new int[4]; {
        values[0]=32;
        values[1]=2;
        values[2]=4;
        values[3]=6;
    }

    public void addScores(int[] values)
    {
        int totalScore = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            totalScore = totalScore + values[i];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayMethod fred = new ArrayMethod();
        int[] scores = { 10, 9, 7, 10 };
        fred.addScores(scores);
        System.out.println(fred[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is supposed to happen with `fred[2]` ? (`fred` being an instance of `ArrayMethod`)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're trying to apply array `[]` syntax to `ArrayMethod fred`, that is of type `ArrayMethod`, not of array.

I guess you should replace it with 
`System.out.println(values[2]);`
, since your array is in `values` variable.

**UPDATE according to the comment below:** Since your variable `values` is `static`, you may access it via `ArrayMethod` class, i.e. 
`System.out.println(ArrayMethod.values[2]);`.

Comment: `values[2]` or `ArrayMethod.values[2]` or `fread.totalScore` (that should also be declared as a field) ?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger since `values` is static, it is not necessary (and pretty ugly, IDEA highlights that) to access it through a variable reference. So `fred.totalScore` won't be an option. `ArrayMethod.values[2]` - yes, thanks, I will update the answer.

Comment: yes, it is static, I had mistaken it with `scores`, which could also be what OP wanted to print... `totalScore` is not an option because it is a local variable, that's why I wrote that it should be declared as a field (or returned from method) so it can be printed - The point is: we don't know what OP really wanted to print

Answer (score 0):

From this line `ArrayMethod fred = new ArrayMethod();`, you are declaring `fred` to be an ArrayMethod, which is an `ArrayMethod` Object. Therefore, you cannot just do `fred[2]`, which is used to get the third element of an `array`.

To achieve what you expected, you need to get the `array` first. i.e. `fred.values[2]`

Sidenotes, the keyword `static` is saying that the variable `values` belongs to the class, instead of one instance of the class(`fred` in your case). If you are creating an instance `fred` from the class, it is likely that you do not need to declare `values` as `static`.

Another thing is that the variable `totalScore` is declared, updated inside the `totalScore()`. It becomes out of scope after the function's execution. If you want to retain the result, you can either return it from the method or make a variable to hold the result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of 'shadowning', your field level variable and method parameter are both same name. Just change the field level variable to something else, like 'globalValues'

Change the following

```
static int[] values = new int[4];
```

To something like

```
static int[] globalValues = new int[4];
```

Then resolve any compilation errors, and ensure your code logic is still intact, and it should all work fine.